# Любые варианты улучшения кода

Tags: c#, инспекция-кода

Есть 2 задачи на ulern.me: [Практика «Limited Size Stack»](https://ulearn.me/course/basicprogramming2/Praktika_Limited_Size_Stack__cdf76069-758c-4a3c-aacb-df3fa877cac5) и [Практика «Отмена»](https://ulearn.me/course/basicprogramming2/Praktika_Limited_Size_Stack__cdf76069-758c-4a3c-aacb-df3fa877cac5), обе ссылаются на один и тот же [проект](https://api.ulearn.me/slides/BasicProgramming2/cdf76069-758c-4a3c-aacb-df3fa877cac5/exercise/student-zip/LimitedSizeStack.zip), поставленную задачу выполнил, все тесты прошли успешно.

Интересно можно ли как-нибудь улучшить/оптимизировать мое решение (новичка). Так же повысить читаемость (по возможности) и по сути, сделать код максимально правильным.

Если есть - найти ошибки.

Просьба писать подробно.

Содержимое Limited Size Stack.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace LimitedSizeStack;

public class LimitedSizeStack<T>
{
    public int Count => _StackList.Count;

    private bool IsFullStack => Count > _MaxCount;
    private bool IsEmptyStack => Count == 0;
    private readonly int _MaxCount;
    private readonly LinkedList<T> _StackList = new();

    public LimitedSizeStack(int maxCount)
    {
        _MaxCount = maxCount;
    }

    public void Push(T item)
    {
        _StackList.AddFirst(item);
        if (IsFullStack)
            _StackList.RemoveLast();
    }

    public T Pop()
    {
        if (IsEmptyStack)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Stack is empty");
        var removedItem = _StackList.First!;
        _StackList.RemoveFirst();
        return removedItem.Value;
    }
}
```

Содержимое ListModel.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace LimitedSizeStack;
public class ListModel<T> 
{
    private bool HistoryActionsNoEmpty => _HistoryActions.Count > 0;

    public readonly List<T> _Items;
    public readonly LimitedSizeStack<Tuple<string, int, T>> _HistoryActions;

    public ListModel(int undoLimit) : this(new List<T>(), undoLimit)
    {
    }

    public ListModel(List<T> items, int undoLimit)
    {
        _HistoryActions = new(undoLimit);
        _Items = items;
    }

    public void AddItem(T item)
    {
        _HistoryActions.Push(GetValue("AddItem", -1, item));
        _Items.Add(item);
    }

    public void RemoveItem(int index)
    {
        _HistoryActions.Push(GetValue("RemoveItem", index, _Items[index]));
        _Items.RemoveAt(index);
    }

    public bool CanUndo()
    {
        return HistoryActionsNoEmpty;
    }

    public void Undo()
    {
        if (CanUndo())
        {
            var lastEdit = _HistoryActions.Pop();
            if (lastEdit.Item1 == "AddItem")
                _Items.RemoveAt(_Items.Count - 1);
            else
                _Items.Insert(lastEdit.Item2, lastEdit.Item3);
        }
    }

    private static Tuple<string, int, T> GetValue(string action, int index, T item)
    {
        return new(action, index, item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Если хотите улучшить, то что именно? Если считаете что нужно повысить читаемость, что именно плохо читается? Максимально правильного кода не существует. Можно наворотить нечиталбельного бреда и он будет работать быстрее пули, а можно наоборот, сделать тормоз в 3 строки кода. Понятие "правильный код" абстрактно. Если рассуждать про поверхностные критерии качества, то код должен быть понятным. Мне он понятный, но написал бы я по-своему. Одна только непонятность есть, почему метод `GetValue` публичный?

Comment: @aepot общую мысль понял, по поводу метода `GetValue` тоже верное замечание, исправил. Благодарю

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    public int Count { get { return StackList.Count; } }
```

можно юзать лямбда-стайл

```
    public int Count => StackList.Count;
```

---

```
    private int MaxCount { get; set; }
```

Зачем тут сеттор? Вы его не используете, у Вас MaxCount ридонли, и это хорошо, но нужно подчеркнуть, убрав сеттор. В конструкторе, он сможет задать значение и без него.

---

```
    public LinkedList<T> StackList { get; private set; }
```

опять ненужный сеттор, и непонятно зачем публично выставлять потроха, убирайте public. Ещё одно замечание - перемешаны public и private члены, а приятнее когда они  сгруппированы.

---

```
    private bool IsFullStack { get { return Count > MaxCount; } }
    private bool IsEmptyStack { get { return Count == 0; ; } }
```

лямбда-стайл?

---

```
    public LimitedSizeStack(int undoLimit)
    {
```

что за undoLimit? У вас протекла абстракция похоже (: переименуйте в maxCount

---

```
        StackList = new();
        MaxCount = undoLimit;
    }
```

можно заинициализировать StackList инлайн

```
private readonly LinkedList<T> StackList = new();
```

---

```
    public void Push(T item)
    {
        StackList.AddFirst(item);
        if (IsFullStack)
            StackList.RemoveLast();
    }
```

Иногда, в код-стайлах принято запрещать отсутствие фигурных скобочек после условия.

---

```
    public T Pop()
    {
        if (IsEmptyStack)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Stack is empty");
        else
        {

            var removedItem = StackList.First ?? throw new ArgumentException();
            StackList.RemoveFirst();
            return removedItem.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

лишняя пустая строка после `else {`.

Странная запоздалая проверка StackList.First на null и тем более не очень ясно с каким аргументом проблема, раз у нас ArgumentException. Не бросайте ArgumentException с пустым конструктором. И мне кажется, вы дважды пытаетесь проверить одно и тоже.

Т.к. вы уверены что в First null не может быть, и у вас включены null refrence type, укажите это явно

```
var removedItem = StackList.First!;
```

---

Нет метода Peek, который возвращает элемент на вершине стека, но не снимает его. Этот метод характерен для интерфейса стеков.

---

Почему выбран LinkedList, а не собственно Stack ? Решение-то хорошее алгоритмически, но со Stack было бы и более читаемо(что важно) и лучше по перформансу (что скорее преждевременная оптимизация).
Если это в учебных целях, то вопрос снимается, но в продакшене должны быть чёткие основания, если вдруг что-то велосипедится, вместо чтобы взять наиболее подходящее решение.

---

Вы отредактировали код в вопросе и теперь у вам там рид-онли поля, а не свойства. Поля принято именовать или с маленькой буквы, или с префикса `_` , или с префикса `m_`, но точно не с заглавной буквы.

Comment: Большую часть понял, от себя сделал `private readonly int MaxCount;` и так же с `StackList`.
Вообще не понял как инициализировать инлайн. Так же, проверка `Stack.First` на `null` сделана, т.к VS почему то ругается на `removedItem` в строке `return removedItem.Value;` CS8602: разыменование пустой строки, хотя есть проверка на пустую строку, т.к `StackList.First` пустой только при `Count = 0`, но при таком условии вылетит `InvalidOperationException("Stack is empty")`. Не понял зачем нужен метод Peek и что там должно быть.

Comment: LinkedList выбран по подсказкам на Ulearn, изначально сделал свой список, но реализовал другой подход и как следствие не проходились тесты на Ulearn и решил сделать на LinkedList. Не Stack т.к по сути задание было сделать этот самый Stack.

Comment: @funny110 ещё этот буфер действий можно реализовать с помощью простого массива и двух интов. Не буду рассказывать, попробуйте сами догадаться, если интересно.

Comment: @funny110 дополнил по всем замечания из вашего комента

Comment: @4per огромное спасибо за ответ и разъяснения, по примеру с `LimitedSizeStack.cs` сделал и `ListModel.cs`, так же честно не знал про возможность поставить `!` при присвоении значения.